# How to access embedded iframe elements with htmlunit driver?

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I want to access the inner content of an embedded iframe with `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient`:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe...>
    #document
    <html>
    <body>
        ...
        <input name="myinput" />
    </body
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I can already grab the `iframe` with:

```
HtmlInlineFrame iframe = (HtmlInlineFrame) page.getElementsByTagName("iframe").get(0);
```

Now I want to grab the input element. But even listing any `input` elements shows only an empty list:

```
NodeList inputs = iframe.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

So what might be wrong here? How can I access the inner of the `embedded iframe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
HtmlInlineFrame iframe = (HtmlInlineFrame) page.getElementsByTagName("iframe").get(0);
HtmlPage innerPage = (HtmlPage) iframe.getEnclosedPage();
NodeList inputs = innerPage.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: `getEnclosedPage()` was the missing part.